# UIPopover dimming view not following screen orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, uipopover

Migrating an old app to iOS8, popovers were going mad.

Weird problem with the "popover dimming view" -> I mean the darkish effect on background views provided by the system when you fire a presentPopoverFromRect.

I happen to have the dimming view in the wrong orientation. When I am in landscape, the dimming view is in portrait (you could see the edges in the middle of the screen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the main xib.

For some reasons the Window was created within a xib. Couldn't find anything wrong with it but I removed the window, created it by code, added the view controller manually, and all went back to normal. I suspected some default settings to be overridden by IB, went back to the faulty window, couldn't find anything wrong.

So, if this happens to you : check you window and/or try to add your window by code.